# Создать одну функцию под две структуры в golang

Tags: golang

Например, такой код :

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Struct01 struct {
    w int
    h int
}
type Struct02 struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (ttt Struct01) Sum() int {return 55}
func (rrr Struct02) Sum() int {return 88}

func main(){

    ttt := Struct01{w:3, h:4}
    rrr := Struct02{x:6, y:8}

    fmt.Println(" : ", ttt.Sum())
    fmt.Println(" : ", rrr.Sum())
}
```

работает. Как правильно делать, чтобы, имея *одну функцию*, например:

```
func Sum() int {return 99}
```

т.е. без ресивера-привязки к конкретной структуре, - эту функцию можно было использовать для этих структур. Думал, для этого пользуют интерфейсы, но сделать так, чтобы ещё и заюзать значения полей этих структур - не получается.

---

Пробовал, что-то по типу :

```
  type Interface01 interface {Sum() int}
  func f1(v Interface01) {v.Sum()}

  // и в main :

  f1(ttt)
  f1(rrr)
```

---

Вот такой вариант (с двумя методами sum и mum и значениями полей структур), - работает. Это то, что я переложил с примеров про интерфейсы в инете под своё ... но так и не проникся в пользе :

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

type Interface01 interface {
    sum()
    mum()
}
func f1(v Interface01) {
    v.sum()
    v.mum()
}

type Struct01 struct {
    w int
    h int
}
type Struct02 struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (ttt Struct01) sum() {fmt.Println("1")}
func (ttt Struct01) mum() {fmt.Println("2")}

func (rrr Struct02) sum() {fmt.Println("3")}
func (rrr Struct02) mum() {fmt.Println("4")}

func main(){
    ttt := Struct01{w:3, h:4}
    rrr := Struct02{x:6, y:8}
    f1(ttt)                       
    fmt.Println("-----------")
    f1(rrr)                       
}
```

Как правильно создать, на моём примере, одну функцию под две (и более) структуры?

---

*UPD_1 :* интерфейс может чем-то помочь? Чтобы сделать так :

```
type Interface01 interface {
    sum()  // сумма значений полей структуры;
    mum()  // перемножил значения полей структуры;
}
func f1(v Interface01) {
    v.sum()
    v.mum()
}

type Struct01 struct {
    w int
    h int
}
type Struct02 struct {
    x int
    y int
}
// одна ф-ция общая, для указанных структур, считает сумму значений полей структуры и не привязана ресивером к структуре;
func sum() {сумма значений полей структуры}
func mum() {перемножил значения полей структуры}

func main(){
    ttt := Struct01{w:3, h:4}
    rrr := Struct02{x:6, y:8}
    // ниже - не работает, - для пояснения, чего хочу 
    f1(ttt) //                       получить 7 (3+4=7)                       
    fmt.Println("-----------")
    f1(rrr) //                       получить 14                                
}
```

---

*UPD_2* Для примера, код без использования интерфейса :

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    type Struct01 struct {
        w int
        h int
    }
    type Struct02 struct {
        x int
        y int
    }

    func (s Struct01) Sum() int { return s.w + s.h }
    func (s Struct02) Sum() int { return s.x + s.y }

    func main() {
        ttt := Struct01{w: 3, h: 4}
        rrr := Struct02{x: 6, y: 8}

        fmt.Println(ttt.Sum())      // 7
        fmt.Println(rrr.Sum())      // 14
    }
```

Comment: В go обобщать типы можно только через интерфейсы. Последний ваш пример как раз про них. Поясните какую именно пользу вы хотите получить?

Comment: @kvark128 , спасибо за помощь. Пытаюсь понять интерфейсы. Думал эта конструкция для удобства .. чтобы юзать одну функцию под разные структуры. Типа : есть общая ф-ция func f1() и вызвав её с аргументом одной структуры - получил, например, сумму значений ее полей (для Struct01 будет 3+4=7) , а вызвав её  же с аргументом структуры Struct02 , - получу 14. Т.е. вот так : f1(ttt) и f1(rrr) ... но чтобы ф-ция func f1() int {искомая сумма} была именно нейтральной, а не с привязкой-ресивером к структуре..., как в том примере, что я привёл в теле вопроса.

Comment: Иначе, так : мне в данном случае-примере интерфейсы могут помочь и как ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обобщать типы можно только по их поведению, то есть по предоставляемым методам. Если для некой структуры требуется получить сумму её полей, то для неё надо реализовать метод, который будет это делать. Например Sum() int.
Далее с множеством различных структур реализующих один набор методов, можно работать единообразно благодаря общему интерфейсу.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Sumer interface {
    Sum() int
}

func f1(v Sumer) {
    fmt.Println(v.Sum())
}

type Struct01 struct {
    w int
    h int
}

func (s Struct01) Sum() int { return s.w + s.h }

type Struct02 struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (s Struct02) Sum() int { return s.x + s.y }

func main() {
    ttt := Struct01{w: 3, h: 4}
    rrr := Struct02{x: 6, y: 8}
    f1(ttt) // 7
    f1(rrr) // 14
}
```

Comment: Да, Ваш код работает, спасибо. Я вот привёл в UPD_2 решение без объявления интерфейса. Собственно, у меня и вопрос : на моём примере какой от интерфейса профит ?  Если строчек кода без него  меньше .. Как можно усложнить мой пример, чтобы профит от интерфейса был очевиден? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: В UPD_2, желая получить некоторый результат, вы работаете с двумя экземплярами различных типов одинаковым образом (вызывая по отдельности у обоих метод Sum). Но это самая общность есть только в вашей голове, в тексте программы её нет. В таком маленьком примере это незаметно, но когда в проекте десятки тысяч строк кода, большое наличие таких неявных намерений превратит его в кровавое месиво.
Явное лучше неявного. Функция принимающая интерфейс явно указывает поведение этого параметра, а какой там тип её в общем случае не волнует. В целом такой подход сильно упрощает понимание кода.